# What causes symbols not to load from a PDB file?

Tags: visual-studio, pdb-files

- Step 1: I build myProgram.exe and generate myProgram.pdb alongside it.
- Step 2: I deliberately cause a crash in myProgram.exe.
- Step 3: I get asked if I want to use Visual Studio as a debugger, and I do that.
- Step 4: Visual Studio loads the symbols from myProgram.pdb.
- Step 5: I check the call stack to identify the (known) place where the crash occurred.
- Step 6: I don't frown or look perplexed, because this is how it should be.

However, if I rename myProgram.exe and myProgram.pdb to SomethingElse.exe and SomethingElse.pdb and repeat these steps, results are mixed from Step 4 onwards. As far as I can tell, on my build machine, VS will always load symbols successfully from the renamed PDB file. However, on my remote target machine, VS will never load symbols - it always tells me that the PDB file does not match the executable. Why not? Is there an obscure rule I am breaking? I am running Visual Studio 2005 everywhere in case that matters.

Comment: I have just tested this on another "remote" machine (in my office) on which this does not occur. Clearly there is something specific to the actual remote machine... which is not networked, and difficult to access except outside of production hours. So I guess I am after tips as to what could cause a simple name change to these files to render their PDBs unusable. If there are problems with new releases, the staff revert back to a renamed executable... and I lose symbol support, making it harder to track down issues there. It's just become really annoying :-(

Comment: It may be a stupid question, but why don't you change the assembly name instead of changing the file name afterwards? Anyway, that is a weird behavior.

Comment: I rename the files when I create a new release - I save a copy as "myProgram [date].exe" in case I need to revert to it. But recently, staff have been reverting to these renamed files due to unhandled exceptions. Tracking those exceptions has been made harder by this weird behaviour.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simple subtle rule being broken here is that the PDB file name appears to be encoded into the EXE file, not derived from the EXE file name. So, for example, if you create "Copy of myProgram.exe" and "Copy of myProgram.pdb" by a simple copy-and-paste in Windows Explorer, it can appear that symbols are being loaded despite the name change. But this will only work so long as the original "myProgram.pdb" file is also present - if you remove "myProgram.pdb" and only have "Copy of myProgram.pdb", the symbols may be compatible, but Visual Studio will not even try to load them.

In a quick-and-dirty test on a remote machine in my office, all that changed was the file name, not the file version, whereas on the actual remote machine, both name and file version were different, so it was never possible for things to appear to work.

Comment: I have a case where the PDB file is not usable even though both the assembly and the PDB file have the same name and location as on build. However, they were moved to another machine, but all the file locations are the same as on the development machine. Still, Visual Studio doesn't consider the PDB file to match the assembly. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio 2013 Update 5 creates broken[1] PDBs for me if my intermediate directory is a subdirectory of the output directory.  My diff to fix the issue

```
-    <IntDir>$(OutDir)/$(TargetName)/</IntDir>
+    <IntDir>$(OutDir)</IntDir>
```

[1] Verified mismatched with windbg's `!itoldyouso`